How do I move the label of DateInterval to the middle in TimelinePlot?
This is my current code for TimelinePlot:
list = {{{1368, 1398}, "aaa"}, {{1399, 1402}, 
    "bbbbbb"}, {{1403, 1424}, "ccccc"}, {{1424, 1425}, 
    "dddd"}, {{1426, 1435}, "eeeee"}};
TimelinePlot[DateInterval[#] -> #2 & @@@ list, 
 PlotLayout -> "Overlapped"]


How do I move the label of DateInterval to the middle (in the red dot place) but not be front of DateInterval?

See GridLines.  Compute a discrete list of the "red" times and put that in a list, GridLines ->{..., None}.

Not sure whether this is documented, but you can use the regular Labeled and set the position to "CenterBubble":
listLabeled = Labeled[DateInterval[#], #2, "CenterBubble"] & @@@ list;
TimelinePlot[listLabeled, PlotLayout -> "Overlapped"]


The other two possible options are "StartBubble" and "EndBubble".

I cannot find any information about this position specification, even I use GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Labeled]. Can you tell me how you discovered this option?

@yode, Labeled is just a wrapper, it doesn't really have any code attached to itself. It is on other functions to interpret what to do with it, in this case, TimelinePlot.

Is there a way to set the font size in a label?

@yode, sure, just change your label directly with Style, for example: Labeled[DateInterval[#], Style[#2, 24], "CenterBubble"] & @@@ list.

See by analogy:
TimelinePlot[{{DateInterval[{DateObject[{1992, 10, 9}, "Day", 
      "Gregorian", -6.`], 
     DateObject[{2009, 10, 18}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`]}], 
   DateInterval[{DateObject[{1992, 10, 16}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`],
      DateObject[{2007, 9, 13}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`]}], 
   DateInterval[{DateObject[{1994, 4, 25}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], 
     DateObject[{2001, 12, 22}, "Day", 
      "Gregorian", -6.`]}]}, {DateInterval[{DateObject[{1988, 11, 2}, 
      "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], 
     DateObject[{1993, 3, 17}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`]}], 
   DateInterval[{DateObject[{1992, 8, 22}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], 
     DateObject[{2007, 10, 25}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`]}], 
   DateInterval[{DateObject[{1996, 12, 19}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`],
      DateObject[{2004, 4, 25}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`]}]}}, 
 GridLines -> {{DateObject[{1990}, "Year"], 
    DateObject[{1997}, "Year"]}, None}]


